# How to create Guest User Account in Ubuntu without Password?

Tags: permissions, users, user-management, user-profile, adduser

I have a desktop computer with kubuntu.
How can I create a Password-less Guest Account.
[Files and History must be deleted at logout]

Comment: The built-in Guest Account will satisfy your needs. No need to do anything!

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-guest-session.html

Answer (score 2):

The built in guest account seems exactly what you need, from the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-guest-session.html) :

> A guest cannot view the home folders of other users, and by default
>   any saved data or changed settings will be removed/reset at logout. It
>   means that each session starts with a fresh environment, unaffected by
>   what previous guests did.

From from the customization [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PasswordlessGuestAccount) on removing a password :

> To begin, create a new user to serve as your guest account. You will
>   be required to enter a password. Enter anything you like, as you will
>   be deleting the password shortly. Be sure to revoke any privileges
>   (such as Administering the system) that you do not want your guests to
>   have.
>
> Once the new account is created, open a terminal and enter the
>   following command:

```
sudo passwd -d guest
```

> Once this is complete, the guest account will have no password. Users
>   will be able to log in from the login screen by merely clicking on the
>   guest account.